# How to insert from CSV file into sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make a program that reads a CSV file and inserts column into a database:

```
# import SQLite module 
import sqlite3
import csv

db = sqlite3.connect("shows.db")

# Setting up the cursor
cr = db.cursor()

# Create tabels and fields
cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shows (id INTEGER, title TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))")
cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genre (show_id INTEGER, genre TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(show_id) REFERENCES shows(id))")

# reading from file 
with open("Favorite TV Shows (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv","r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        cr.execute(f"INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES ('{title}')")
```

but when I run the code this error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lesson4.py", line 20, in <module>
    cr.execute(f"INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES ('{title}')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "S": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting into database syntax should be like this:

```
cr.execute("INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES (%s)", (title,))
db.commit()
```

You should commit after inserting into database using python.
**See more** [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp)